# Cannot upload video. $_FILE is empty

Tags: php, video, file-upload

I encounter an error when it does't allow me to Upload Video. I add `print_r($_FILES)` to basically check what is inside the file array. Pls Help!!!

This is My php Code:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $allowedExts = array( "mp4", "wma");
    $target_dir = "temp/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $vidoeFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "video/mp4")  && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] < 5120000) && in_array($vidoeFileType, $allowedExts))
    {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    }else{
        echo "Not upload | Name: ".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] ." | Type: ".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] . "| Size: ". $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] . "<br/>";
print_r($_FILES);
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    //check file is error or not
    // if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] > 0)
 //    {
 //     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] . "<br />";
 //    }


    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5120) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }


    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }


}else{



?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000000000"  type="hidden"/>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

}

?>
```

Output:

```
Not upload | Name: aiu.mp4 | Type: | Size: 0
Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => aiu.mp4 [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) ) Sorry, your file was not uploaded.
```

It only show the video name and error.

Comment: var_dump($_POST); what is the output of this?

Comment: `[error] => 1` = **The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.** http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: @AmitRajput The output : `array(2) { ["MAX_FILE_SIZE"]=> string(15) "100000000000000" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Upload" }`

Comment: @JSTai what is the size of uploading file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[error] => 1`

This error means that the file size exceeds PHP's max filesize limit.
Increase it with a php.ini.

```
upload_max_filesize = 7M
```

You also should make sure your ini's `post_max_size` is larger than (or equal to) `upload_max_filesize` since file uploads count against total POST size.

You may also, depending on how large your file is, have to increase your `memory_limit`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, PHP is set to allow uploads of files with a size of 2MB or less. Try increasing the following values in php.ini, for example: memory_limit = 32M upload_max_filesize = 24M post_max_size = 32M. like below:

```
 <?php
// overwrite default uload max file size
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '50M');

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $allowedExts = array( "mp4", "wma");
    $target_dir = "temp/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $vidoeFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "video/mp4")  && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] < 5120000) && in_array($vidoeFileType, $allowedExts))
    {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    }else{
        echo "Not upload | Name: ".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] ." | Type: ".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] . "| Size: ". $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] . "<br/>";
print_r($_FILES);
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    //check file is error or not
    // if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] > 0)
 //    {
 //     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] . "<br />";
 //    }


    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > $_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE']) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }


    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }


}else{



?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000000000"  type="hidden"/>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

}

?>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: The result is still the same, I will try to modify php.ini in xampp.

Comment: @JSTai what is the size of your file uploading?

Comment: I have changed the condition ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > $_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE']). Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Steps to solve this issue:

**************************I am Using Xamp here******************************

1. Go to Xampp->PHP->Php.config
2. Change the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size  from 2M to 50M
3. Do similar changes in php.ini-Development
4. Do similar changes in php.ini-Production.

Note*
Make sure you restart your server.

Thanks

Comment: how do you know the op is using xamp?

Comment: That's why i mentioned here "I am talking about Xampp here "

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for dropping by. I am using xampp.

Comment: Hi guy, I try to change the following:

Comment: Thanks, Problem Solve.